# Extending a library's struct/interface

Tags: go

**Use case**

I am using Shopify's sarama libary which is a client library. More specifically I am using the `ClusterAdmin` struct which is great, however I want to add another method `ListDetailedTopics` to it and I must call ClusterAdmin's non public methods.

https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/admin.go

**Problem**

I am not sure how I could "extend" the exported struct by my own method. I tried this:

```
func (ca *sarama.ClusterAdmin) ListDetailedtopics() {
  b, err := ca.findAnyBroker() // This is a private method I need to call
}
```

That did not work because "invalid receiver type *sarama.ClusterAdmin (sarama.ClusterAdmin is an interface type)". How can I extend the struct/interface by my own methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **cannot** extend the interface outside its package.

What you can do instead is define a new interface that implements the old interface and then add your new method to the new interface. For example:

```
type ExtendedClusterAdmin interface {
   sarama.ClusterAdmin
   ListDetailedtopics()
}
```

---

If you want to use private function within the package then you would have to do it inside the package itself. For example, with a patch.

Comment: Uff literally I can only create wrappers around the exported types since I cannot call any private methods?

Comment: actually `sarama.ClusterAdmin` it is meant to be implemented by yourself if needed. Just copy the struct implementing it and add what ever you need. I don't think you need to extend the interface itself.